# Button not auto margin when set background

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-button

I have problem in create layout android. I use linearlayout to add 4 buttons inside this with

```
param layout_width="0dp"
```

and

```
layout_weight="1"
```

All button margin is very good.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lnlayout" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="#000000">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnEffectVideo"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/effect_video"
        android:padding="5dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnDgAddMusic"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="@string/add_music" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnDgMoreText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="@string/more_text" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSubmit"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="@string/save" />
</LinearLayout>
```

But when i change background button it not margin.

CustomButton.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:state_pressed="true" >
  <shape>
  <solid
   android:color="#696969" />
  <stroke
   android:width="1dp"
   android:color="#FFFFFF" />
  <corners
   android:radius="3dp" />
  </shape>
 </item>
  <item>
  <shape>
  <gradient
   android:startColor="#F6BF00"
   android:endColor="#992f2f"
   android:angle="270" />
  <stroke
   android:width="1dp"
   android:color="#FFFFFF" />
  <corners
   android:radius="5dp" />
 </shape>
 </item>
</selector>
```

please help me solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just set margin with button like

```
android:layout_margin="10dp"
```

It will take all margin from all side :)

Comment: Thanks! it work. But i don't understand what happen.

Comment: actually when we take button then only we can see that button making design like button but in android that view area which also include in that view in ur case that is button if u see practically then just click on that button in xml graphical view and see what area will select :)

Comment: +1 accept and vote up dude, I'm new mem, i don't know how to do that. sorry :D